# SERILOG: Difference between ForContext and and

Tags: serilog

I am using the static Logger with the following setup:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341)
.CreateLogger();
```

with the following in all my micro-services:

```
_log = Log.ForContext<GameBase>()
            .ForContext("CustomerID", CustomerID);
```

This code inserts an CustomerID property in each event but not to the message body.

Question: Is there a way to enrich all logs for this context so that the MESSAGE BODY contains this information as well?  Like an enricher that would prepend a string to each message body?  There are some items I really want to see in the events without having to drill down on each event.

Also, I'm not finding much documentation on the Enrichers. Is there one to not display the full context path?

Answer (score 2):

The message body is configured at the Sink level, usually by defining an `outputTemplate` (if the Sink supports it, not all of them do). By using the `ForContext` you are making the `CustomerID` property available to all messages written to this log instance, but it's on the Sink configuration that you define how this property will be used / shown.

You can see examples in Serilog's documentation under **[Formatting Output](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output)**

[image: Formatting Output]

Comment: Ooooo... OutputTemplate is AWESOME... except that it only seems to work for Console.  Not for .WriteTo.Seq. Right?  Is there a way to get it to work with .Seq?

Comment: Seq doesn't have an output template, but you can [select properties to be displayed as tags and see them for every message](https://github.com/datalust/seq-tickets/issues/138#issuecomment-65068079)